# Android FragmentPagerAdapter is deprecated

Tags: java, android

I have a warning: FragmentPagerAdapter is deprecated.
Here my code:

```
package com.sweetieapps.librarianpro;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentListTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragmentList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentListTitles.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentListTitles.get(position);
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentListTitles.add(title);
    }
}
```

I found a possible solution here: [FragmentPagerAdapter deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778106/fragmentpageradapter-deprecated)
But it's in Kotlin.

The warning  is on the word: **super**

```
//Here
super(fm);
```

Comment: super(fm,FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)

Comment: deprecated use ViewPager2 https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [FragmentPagerAdapter constrctor documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#FragmentPagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)):

> This constructor is deprecated.
>   use [`FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#FragmentPagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20int)) with [`BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)

So replace `super(fm)` with:

```
super(fm, FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
```

Comment: but the class itself is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

It's time to start to move on ViewPager2 - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2