# Get null FragmentManager/Activity in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

#### Scene

I want to update the content of several `fragment`s once I get the response from some HTTP requests.

#### My Idea

My implementation is something like this:
[image: Idea]
`onCreate` of activity, Bind `ViewPagerAdapter` to it. Then trigger the HTTP request to get data.
Once the request succeeds, update the content in Fragment.

#### Code

`sendRequest`. --> `adapter.updateFragment(bundle)` --> `fragment.updateData(bundle);`

**Activity**

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("DetailedProduct-LifeCycle", "------------onCreate------------");

    ...

    // Set ViewPager
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Send Request
    sendRequest();

    ...
}

public void sendRequest(){
    Log.d("DetailedProduct", requestUrl);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            requestUrl,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    LinearLayout progressView = findViewById(R.id.progressView);
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bundle.putString("detail", response.toString());
                    Log.d("DetailedProduct", "get data:"+response.toString());
                    Log.d("DetailedProduct", "final Data:" + bundle.toString());
                    adapter.updateFragment(bundle);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("DetailedProduct", "Cannot get detailed data");
                }
            });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

**Adapter**

```java
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private SellerFragment sellerFragment;
    private ShippingFragment shippingFragment;
    private ProductSummaryFragment productSummaryFragment;
    private FragmentManager fragManager;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager);
        sellerFragment = new SellerFragment();
        shippingFragment = new ShippingFragment();
        productSummaryFragment = new ProductSummaryFragment();
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // ToDo:
        Log.d("ViewPager", position+": ------------getItem----------");

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                if(productSummaryFragment==null){
                    productSummaryFragment = new ProductSummaryFragment();
                }
                return productSummaryFragment;
            case 1:
                if(sellerFragment==null){
                    sellerFragment = new SellerFragment();
                }
                return sellerFragment;
            case 2:
                if(shippingFragment==null){
                    shippingFragment = new ShippingFragment();
                }
                return shippingFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public void updateFragment(Bundle bundle){
        Log.d("ViewPager", "------------updateData----------");
        productSummaryFragment.updateData(bundle);
        sellerFragment.updateData(bundle);
        shippingFragment.updateData(bundle);
    }
}
```

**Fragment Sample**

```java
public class ShippingFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView shippingSection;
    protected JSONObject data;
    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.shipping_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        shippingSection = view.findViewById(R.id.shipping_info_section_content);
        setData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        Log.d("ShippingFragment", "-----------onAttach----------");
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof AppCompatActivity){
            Log.d("ShippingFragment", "---------bind mActivity Success-------");
            mActivity = (AppCompatActivity)context;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        Log.d("ShippingFragment", "-----------onDetach----------");
        super.onDetach();
    }
    // Same for all fragments
    public void  updateData(Bundle bundle){
        Log.d("ShippingFragment", "--------------updateData------------");
        setArguments(bundle);

        if(mActivity==null){
            Log.e("ShippingFragment", "------------activity disappears----------");
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
}
```

#### Problem

The log shows that `updateData` for fragments at position 0,1 works well. but it incurs error for the fragment at position 2.

[image]

The difference I found is that the adaptor didn't call `getItem` for position 2, which means  `onAttach` of `shippingFragment` doesn't been called. So `mActivity` does not exist.

Without `mActivity`, using `getFragmentManager` in `shippingFragment`, get this error:
[image]

My intuition tells me that the problem must from the **work flow of adapter** or the **fragmentManager transaction**. But as a beginner of Android, I have spent all day on them, no clue.

How to fix it? By the way, is there better way to implement my scene?

Comment: plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778106/fragmentpageradapter-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)` to make sure all 3 fragments are attached to the activity once the activity open.

Comment: Are there potential problems in my code? Memory leak etc.

Comment: @Zheyuuu No, to the best of my knowledge, ViewPaper inits just 2 fragments at once, example, the first one will be destroyed when the third one is displayed, when user want to back to the first one, it's will be initialized again. The `setOffscreenPapgeLimit(3)` sure that the viewPager will keep 3 fragments at once.