# `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` is deprecated

Tags: java, android

How to fix the deprecation warning for the below?

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new AllItemsFragment();
            case 1:
                return new AvailableItemsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new BorrowedItemsFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3; // Three pages
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "All";
            case 1:
                return "Available";
            case 2:
                return "Borrowed";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778106/fragmentpageradapter-deprecated) are not useful and neither is the ambiguous [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter) which recommends switching to a `ViewPager2` without any useful examples or indications on how to do so, just this:

```
Switch to androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 and use androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter instead.
```

Comment: Migration guide https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/vp2-migration